# DB not accepting space characters of chinese languages

Tags: php

My website contains data in Chinese language. When I am trying to save it in DB it is not accepting spaces instead it is replacing '?'. I have tried using UTF-8, utf8mb4, utf-8 charset.

What do I have to use to accept the Chinese language in DB columns type?

Comment: change the datatype to nvarchar

Answer (score 0):

Do some encoding and then insert it into your DB, so it will accept it and you will get the same when you decode it.

There are lot of encodings available. You can use gzcompress(), base64encode(),etc